# Angular js - a simple loop on a json won't work

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, for-loop

Here is my simple code:

in `app.js`:

```
$http.get($rootScope.config.app_ws+'jsons/json.json').success(function(response) {
            $rootScope.config.app_genres =  response;
        });
```

the `json.json`:

```
{ 
    "genres":{  

                "Ambient":{},
                "Alternative":{},
                "Blues":{},
                "Chillout":{},
                "Classical":{},
                "Country":{},
                "Dance":{},
                "Dubstep":{},
                "Electronic":{},
                "Folk":{},
                "Grunge":{},
                "Hip Hop":{},
                "House":{},
                "Indie":{},
                "Jazz":{},
                "Latin":{},
                "Metal":{},
                "Opera":{},
                "Pop":{},
                "Punk":{},
                "R&B":{},
                "Reggae":{},
                "Rock":{},
                "Ska":{},
                "Soul":{},
                "Vocal":{},
                "Funk":{},
                "Lounge":{},
                "Geek":{}
    }
}
```

the `HTML`:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in config.app_genres.genres">
<span class="span3x3" ng-if="$first"><a href="">Others</a></span>
<span class="span3x3"><a href="">{{i}}</a></span>
<div class="row-fluid" ng-if="($index%3) == 1"></div>
```

i'm just trying listing in `html` all the json genres names , so for example Alternative, Ambient, Pop, Rock, etc but actually it prints `{}` instead of the genre Name.

What's happening?

Comment: @steo no man really nothing in console :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Genres` is an object, not a array. This means it doen't have a list of elements, but a list of (key, value) pairs. In your case, the keys are the names of the genres and the values are empty objects.

What happens is that `ng-repeat` iterates by default on the values. So you have several options:

If you only need the genre names, try a JSON array instead:

```
{
    "Genres": [
        "Pop",
        "Rock",
        ...
        "Jazz"
    ]
}
```

If you need further details, iterate on both keys and values:

```
<div ng-repeat="(genre, details) in config.app_genres.genres">
```

With a JSON like:

```
{
    "Genres": {
        "Jazz": {
            "songs": 50
        },
        "Pop": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now that I look at the `JSON` file it actually prints the right value. 
If you see, you are using an "`object literal`" while you should have an `array` instead

```
"Genres": ["Ambient", "Alternative", .., "Jazz"]
```

At the very moment, the value of every **genre** is actually `{ }` which is the value that is printed in your `HTML`.

Comment: ok, but sorry what's wrong here? http://pastebin.com/GyQEXVGc why jsonlint won't validate it? :/